# passing same argument from outer function to inner function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a inner function function

```
def inner_function(scenario = 'name',myopic_variable = True):

    if scenario == 'name':
        print('Name')

    if myopic_variable == True:
        print('Myopic is True')
```

and the main function like this.

```
def main_function(scenario = 'name',myopic_variable = True):
    inner_function()
```

Now when I am calling main function like this it works fine

```
main_function(scenario = 'name',myopic_variable = True)
```

but when i change myopic_variable = False
it still gives me the same output why?

Comment: You do not need to compare `if myopic_variable == True:`, you can just write `if myopic_variable:`

Answer (score 1):

`def inner_function(scenario = 'name',myopic_variable = True):` You are passing a default value of true here.

```
def main_function(scenario = 'name',myopic_variable = True):
    inner_function()
```

Here, no parameters are passed to `inner_functions()`, it prints `True`, the default value. To make it correct, call `inner_function(myopic_variable = myopic_variable)`

Comment: If it solves your purpose, consider marking this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because you are using something called default arguments in python.
To understand what you are facing, let's take an example:

```
def inner_fun(a=True):
     print(a)

inner_fun()
```

will print True because we are not passing any argument while calling this function. It will thus takr the default argument which is True here.

If you run `inner_fun(False)` , it'll print False because this time you are passing an argument in the function which has higher precedence than the default value.